# Horizontal plane for surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

"A plane is horizontal when $z=a$, where a is some constant. For which values of a does $z=a$ describe a tangent plane for the surface

$z = x*y*e^{\frac{-2x^2+6y^2}{2}+1}$

I tried differentiating with respect to $x$ and $y$ and set these equal to $0$ to get

$\cfrac d{dx} = (2x^2-1)*y*(-e^{-x^2+3y^2+1}) = 0$

which has solutions 
$ x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$,
$ x = \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}$, and
$ y = 0$

$\cfrac d{dy} = x(6y^2+1)*e^{-x^2+3y^2+1}$
which has only $x=0$ as it's real solution.

I'm trying to find some $(x,y)$ I can plug into $z$ to get out my horizontal plane at $z=a$, but obviously I've overlooked something since $x=0$ and $y=0$ gives $z=0$.

What is my mistake?

Comment: $a=0$ is your answer then.

Comment: I believe I'm missing another solution as well (possibly 2).

Comment: What makes you think so?

Comment: If I plot the function, it looks like there should be one positive (above the function) and one below on the negative z axis

Comment: Nvm, it was supposed to be -(2x^2+6y^2), hence the complex solutions for d/dy which I didn't get. Solved.